# Is it possible to make randomly colored objects via the compositor in Blender Internal?

Tags: materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

Is it possible to have a per object random value between 0-1 that can be used to mix two colors in Blender Internal?

I am used to using the Object Info node in Cycles to accomplish this effect, however I have been unable to find an equivalent in Blender Internal without using third party addons.

Comment: You could hijack the object color property; set each object's object color randomly with python, then get that into the node tree with a shadeless material that has object color enabled.

Comment: hmm, not a bad idea

Comment: @gandalf3 I ended up using your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up using is to give each object a random black and white object color with a simple script, and then to render those colors out as a separate render-layer to be used as a mix factor.

The code:

```
import bpy
import random

#set sel to selected objects
sel = bpy.context.selected_objects

#for each object in the selected group, assign a random object color
for ob in sel:
   n = random.random()
   ob.color = (n, n, n, 1)    #this sets all color channels to "n" resulting in b/w color
```

This results in each object having a random (not necessarily unique) object color.

---

I then made a new shadeless material that derived the color from the object color:

[image]

And made a new render-layer with it as the override material:

[image]

This resulted in a perfect mask that I could use to mix elements and colors in the compositor with:

[image: random color mask]

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively simple to do, pick your add on: **Animation Nodes** or **Sverchok**, and per Object color is easily done via Color props of an Object. You can use AN Object Attribute Out or SV Object Set nodes to change Object Color.

[image]

Turn on Object Color in Material, and change give different color per Object, easily visualized and will render in BI.

Comment: My apologies, I did not specify this originally. I can't use add-ons not included in Blender.

Comment: Ah... that's pity.

Comment: Python, drivers, or expression is the way to go then.... but why only Add-On inside Blender? Very limiting.

Comment: I know it's limiting, but it is required for the context I am using this project in.